# What causes DB2 to have log file times out of order?

Tags: logging, db2

I routinely see the following in the logs of a DB2 LUW 9.7.4 server:

```
-rw------- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129M Feb 23 11:20 S0000045.LOG
-rw------- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129M Feb 23 12:10 S0000046.LOG
-rw------- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129M Feb 23 13:05 S0000047.LOG
-rw------- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129M Feb 23 13:47 S0000048.LOG
-rw------- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129M Feb 23 14:40 S0000049.LOG
-rw------- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129M Feb 23 14:50 S0000050.LOG
-rw------- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129M Feb 23 14:40 S0000051.LOG
```

As you can see, log 50 has been written to *after* log 51 has. If log 51 is no longer the newest, as a secondary log, shouldn't it be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Well this means that one of you apps was holding S0000050.LOG for 10 sec longer than S0000051.LOG ..